# My NSButton with icon has no icon

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, appkit, nsbutton

I have an NSButton in a nib that is set to an icon, and only an icon:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode with the button selected, showing its image name set to NSQuickLookTemplate]

When I run the app, the icon, despite being [one of the images provided by AppKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSImageNameQuickLookTemplate), is missing:

[image: Screenshot of the button in my app at run time, showing no image]

What's going on here? Why isn't my button's icon showing up?

Comment: It's not "only an icon", you have a title in there too.  Is the console spewing any auto layout errors?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: True, there is a title, but the button is set to show only the icon. (I set the title for accessibility purposes, although I just checked and VoiceOver isn't showing that, either. Accessibility Inspector says it has no title. Curiouser and curiouser.) Nothing in the Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  In my little sample app I just created, I was able to get the icon to appear (took a bit of doing, though).  Summed up, you need to change the button type to "Bevel" and increase the height if necessary.

Apparently "Push"-style NSButton types are too narrow to display the icon comfortably.